# H.264 adding dark anti-aliasing even on high444 yuv444p

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, h.264, libx264

I have a PNG file with white on red and no antialiasing at all - each pixel is either white or red, but when I encode it to MP4 using `ffmpeg -i test.png  -profile:v high444 -pix_fmt yuv444p  -loop 1 -crf 0 -framerate 30 -c:v libx264 -t 15  test444.mp4` the output gets dark pixels added and the white color gets changed.  See zoomed in screenshot below for before and after.  I played the mp4 file with `ffplay` btw.

[image]

Original PNG below:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the original PNG?

Comment: @Mulvya added original PNG - thx

Comment: This appears to be a scaler issue, not the encoder. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Mulvya is there a way to disable or change the scaler to see if that resolves it? I tried using bitexact in light of your comment but it didn't solve it. Thanks

Comment: How did you view and take the screenshot of the output?

Comment: @Mulvya Viewed using `ffplay test444.mp4` and screenshot taken using Greenshot (note that a screenshot of the PNG file has no issues - only of the resulting MP4 file). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rendering artifact, not an actual error.

See

```
ffplay test444.mp4 -vf scale=iw*16:-1:flags=neighbor
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i test444.mp4 roundtrip.png
```

You should see no black pixels.

**Update**: ffplay downsamples YUV inputs to 420 before final conversion to RGB.

```
[swscaler @ 0000000005a82800] bicubic scaler, from yuv444p to yuv420p using MMXEXT
```

You can avoid artifacts by directly calling pixel format filter.

```
ffplay test444.mp4 -vf format=bgra
```

Comment: How weird - I wonder why the player would possibly decide to add those dark pixels.

Comment: I think decoder/display uses yuv420

Comment: That's right. See workaround.